# Charge object not available on first page load

Tags: plugins, plugin-charge

I have a custom donation form that I'm using that includes some custom Craft fields. Two of those fields are dropdowns which I populated with options from within my Craft admin panel.

Since this is a custom form, it must use Stripe.js, so I have the following lines in my template per the [tutorial on the SquareBit](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge/usage/quickstart/using-stripe-js) site:

```
{% includeJsResource('charge/js/stripe_v2.min.js') %}
{% includeJsResource('charge/js/jquery.charge.js') %}
{% includejs %}
    $(this).charge();
{% endincludejs %}
```

Here are my Payment options that are set inside the `<form>` declaration:

```
{% set chargePaymentOptions = { 'allowDynamic' : true, 'planCurrency': 'usd', } %}

{{ craft.charge.setPaymentOptions(chargePaymentOptions) }}
```

I borrowed some code from the Charge plugin examples for initializing the select fields like so:

```
{{ forms.selectField({
     label: 'Donation Recurrence',
     name: 'donationRecurrence',
     id: 'donationRecurrence',
     options: (charge is defined ? charge.donationRecurrence.options),
     value: (charge is defined ? charge.donationRecurrence),
     errors: (charge is defined ? charge.getErrors('donationRecurrence'))
}) }}

{{ forms.selectField({
     label: 'Would you like to donate to a specific cause?',
     name: 'donationDesignation',
     id: 'donationDesignation',
     options: (charge is defined ? charge.donationDesignation.options),
     value: (charge is defined ? charge.donationDesignation),
     errors: (charge is defined ? charge.getErrors('donationDesignation'))
}) }}
```

As you can see, the select fields get their options from the aforementioned pre-populated custom Craft fields. Those options do *not* show up on *first* page load, but if the form is subsequently submitted and comes back with errors, then the select field options appear.

I figured out that on the first page load, doing a `dump(charge)` shows that the `charge` object does not exist until the page has been reloaded after the form was submitted.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: My current workaround, get the field directly and set this to the select field options:
`{% set donationRecurrenceOptions = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('donationRecurrence').settings.options %}`

Comment: Would you mind adding your workaround as an answer, @tofirius?

Answer (score 1):

My current workaround: Get the select field directly and set its options to the select field options:

`{% set donationRecurrenceOptions = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('donationRecurrence').settings‌​.options %}`